# What is wrong with my char to datetime conversion in SAS?

Tags: sas

Good day. In Base SAS, I tried to convert character to datetime format. Character is coming from macro variable. I tried to convert it but it failed.
It is complaining invalid format $DATETIME indicating my conversion failed.
Now i am lost.

i am getting this error:

```
MPRINT(ALFRED):   data _null_;
MPRINT(ALFRED):   set ncpdm.ncp_load_tnbt_201811 (obs=1);
MPRINT(ALFRED):   where st_datetime ^= . and sp_datetime ^= .;
MPRINT(ALFRED):   call symputx("sp_datetime",sp_datetime);
MPRINT(ALFRED):   run;

NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set NCPDM.NCP_LOAD_TNBT_201811.
      WHERE (st_datetime not = .) and (sp_datetime not = .);
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


1858869000
MPRINT(ALFRED):   data linkbacktoretnbt;
MPRINT(ALFRED):   set linkbacktore;
NOTE 137-205: Line generated by the invoked macro "ALFRED".
5801          data linkbacktoretnbt; set linkbacktore; SystemPeakDate2=&sp_datetime; SystemPeakDate=input(SystemPeakDate2,best32.); format SystemPeakDate datetime.; format data_dttm datetime.; run;   data ncp_load_re; set ncpdm.ncp_load_re; run;  proc sql
;
                                                                                                                                                          _________
                                                                                                                                                          48
5801     !  create
ERROR 48-59: The format $DATETIME was not found or could not be loaded.

MPRINT(ALFRED):   SystemPeakDate2=1858869000;
MPRINT(ALFRED):   SystemPeakDate=input(SystemPeakDate2,best32.);
MPRINT(ALFRED):   format SystemPeakDate datetime.;
MPRINT(ALFRED):   format data_dttm datetime.;
MPRINT(ALFRED):   run;
```

My code:

```
    %macro alfred();

* Get system peak;
%let sp_datetime=;
data _null_;
    set ncpdm.ncp_load_tnbt_&Period (obs=1);
    where st_datetime ^= . and sp_datetime ^= .;
    call symputx("sp_datetime",sp_datetime);
run;
%put &sp_datetime;

proc sql;
create table linkbacktore as
select a.*,
b.max_power
from /*ncpdm.ncp_load_re*/ distinctfulljoin /*REsourceFULLSCADA2*/ a
left join groupedscadappu b
on a.re_ca_no=b.re_ca_no
and a.re_switch_no=b.re_switch_no;
run;

* Get system peak from TNBT Metering;
%let sp_datetime=;
data _null_;
    set ncpdm.ncp_load_tnbt_&Period (obs=1);
    where st_datetime ^= . and sp_datetime ^= .;
    call symputx("sp_datetime",sp_datetime);
run;
%put &sp_datetime;


data linkbacktoretnbt;
set linkbacktore;
SystemPeakDate2=&sp_datetime;
SystemPeakDate=input(SystemPeakDate2,best32.);
format SystemPeakDate datetime.;
format data_dttm datetime.;
run;


%mend;
%alfred;
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to associate a numeric format with a character variable.

```
1    data _null_;
2       length SystemPeakDate $32.;
3       format SystemPeakDate datetime.;
                              ---------
                              48
ERROR 48-59: The format $DATETIME was not found or could not be loaded.

4       run;
```

In a data step you can omit the $sign, SAS will supply it.  Consider this example.

```
51   data _null_;
52      x = 'xyz';
53      format x 2.;
54      f = vformat(x);
55      put x= f=;
56      run;

x=xy f=$CHAR2.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says what is wrong. You are trying to attach a numeric format to a character variable. So SAS tries to be helpful and assumes you just forgot to put the `$` prefix on the format name.  But then it cannot find a character format named `$DATETIME`. Hence the error message.

Looks like the variable `SystemPeakDate` that you are getting from your input dataset is a character variable?

Also why are you doing this two step process?

```
SystemPeakDate2=&sp_datetime;
SystemPeakDate=input(SystemPeakDate2,best32.);
```

You are creating SystemPeakDate2 as a numeric variable to start with.  See the MPRINT lines in your LOG.

```
MPRINT(ALFRED):   SystemPeakDate2=1858869000;
MPRINT(ALFRED):   SystemPeakDate=input(SystemPeakDate2,best32.);
```

Your attempt to convert it to a number using INPUT() function is just going to force SAS to first convert it to a character string so that the INPUT() function has a character string to read from.

If you want to convert `SystemPeakDate` from character to numeric then use the INPUT() function with an informat that generates numeric values.  So perhaps you want something like:

```
SystemPeakDate2=input(SystemPeakDate,anydtdtm32.);
format SystemPeakDate2 datetime19. ;
```

What informat to use in the INPUT() function call depends on what the character strings in the source variable look like.  The ANYDTDTM informat will attempt to guess what the values represent for a number of different character representations of datetime values.  But if your original values have the date part in MDY or DMY order then it might not make the right decision for ambiguous values like '10/12/2018'.  So it is better to use an informat that matches how your actual values are constructed.

If you want to convert a numeric to character then perhaps you want to use the PUT() function instead?

```
SystemPeakDate=put(&sp_datetime,datetime19.-L);
```

Then there is no need to attach a format to the character variable SystemPeakDate.  SAS already knows how to display character variables without any special formatting instructions.